# JQuery not working with classes generated with Jinja

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, jinja2

When referring to classes that have been generated with Jinja, JQuery no longer recognises them and works.

This is the code I have.

```
{% for name,quantity in movies %}
        <script>
            $(".pointer_{{name}}").click(function(){
                $(".pointer_{{name}}").hide()
            });
        </script>
        <div class="movies">
            <div class="right_display">
                <h3> {{name}} 
                    <span style="float:right;">
                        <label class="pointer pointer_{{name}}">
                        <input class="isRemoved" type="checkbox" name="isOnPage_{{name}}" value="removed">[X]</label>
                    </span>
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively,

```
<script>
    $(".pointer").click(function(){
        $(".pointer").hide()
    });
</script>
```

works, but is not what I am after.

Cheers.

Comment: And what is the value for `{{name}}`? Any space in it? And I would place the script after the HTML markup, in the loop.

Comment: But have you tryed using `$(this)`?? Like in `$(".pointer").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });` It would be simplier. And need only one script for all...

Comment: You're registering the event handler before the element exists.

Comment: @Blurp that was the issue. Cheers